# Elegantly latticed triangle centers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, triangles, plane-geometry

Take a non-right scalene triangle and calculate [triangle centers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCenter.html). How many distinct lattice points in the vicinity of the origin can be covered by these triangle centers?

The triangle $ ((4\sqrt3, 3\sqrt3), (-4\sqrt3, -3\sqrt3), (3, 12))$ is the best I've found so far, back-solving from the incenter, orthocenter, and centroid. Green points are rational centers, red points are non-rational centers.
[image: elegantly latticed triangle]

Coordinates of the first 13 centers are $$((3,6), (1,4), (-3,4), (9,4), (3,4), (89,148)/21,(183,264)/43)$$ $$( (-3,0), (-27,126)/43, (0,3), (3,9), (12,21)/4, (77,100)/17)$$

Are there any triangles with centers that will cover more distinct lattice points near the origin than this triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are $3$ candidates (coordinates of vertices and draft sketches),
but only $112$ first centers have been considered/drawn here yet.

First and second triangles are similar ($\sqrt{2}$-scaled and $45^\circ$-rotated).

**First triangle**: $(14,\;-2), \quad (-7-3\sqrt{7},\; 1+3\sqrt{7}), \quad (-7+3\sqrt{7},\; 1-3\sqrt{7})$;

[image]

Few first integer centers:
$X_1(2,-2)$, $X_2(0,0)$, $X_3(2,10)$, $X_4(-4,-20)$, $X_5(-1,-5)$, $X_8(-4,4)$, $X_{10}(-1,1)$, $X_{11}(5,1)$, $X_{12}(1,-3)$.

**Second triangle**: $(-3,\; 3\sqrt{7}+4), \quad(-3, \;4-3\sqrt{7}),\quad (6,\;-8)$;

[image]

Few first integer centers:
$X_1(0,-2)$, $X_2(0,0)$, $X_3(6,4)$, $X_4(-12,-8)$, $X_5(-3,-2)$, $X_8(0,4)$, $X_{10}(0,1)$, $X_{11}(3,-2)$, $X_{12}(-1,-2)$.

**Third triangle**: $(x_A,\; y_A), \quad(x_B, \;y_B),\quad (x_C,\;y_C)$,

where 

 $x_A,x_B,x_C$ are roots of cubic equation $x^3-39x-16=0$;

 $y_A,y_B,y_C$ are roots of cubic equation $x^3-147x+578=0$;

$(x_A,y_A) \approx(-0.412050259613482,\; 9.15947187400213)$;

$(x_B,y_B) \approx(-6.02876924833151,\; 4.58967278123278)$;

$(x_C,y_C) \approx( 6.44081950794499,\; -13.7491446552349)$;

[image]

Few first integer centers:
$X_1(-2,4)$, $X_2(0,0)$, $X_3(4,-2)$, $X_4(-8,4)$, $X_5(-2,1)$, $X_8(4,-8)$, $X_{10}(1,-2)$, $X_{11}(-2,7)$, $X_{12}(-2,3)$.

(Free for further research and improve).

Comment: All these examples have nice property: $$(x_A+x_B+x_C)/3 = p;$$ $$(x_A^2+x_B^2+x_C^2)/3=q;$$ $$(x_A^3+x_B^3+x_C^3)/3=r;$$ where $p,q,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ (w.l.o.g., $p$ can be set to zero); (and $y_A,y_B,y_C$ $-$ similarly).